# How to attach land_pad model on top of rover model in PX4-Autopilot Gazebo simulation

Tags: gazebo-simu, px4

I want to attach the land_pad model from px4-autopilot on top of the rover model for a project I'm working on. Since I'm completely new to px4, I have no idea how to do that. If you know how to do that or point me to a tutorial/documentation, it would be really helpful.

I thought of building a new custom model including both rover and the landpad would be the solution but I'm not sure if that is the correct approach. Even if it is the correct approach, I don't know how to do so.